# Creating a Gridview control in Bootstrap

Tags: html, gridview, datatable, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a Gridview like control in bootstrap 4 by following this [post](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html). Everything seems to work fine except search bar, pagination bar etc. are getting stretched to the boundary of the page. I tried to fix table width but it is working properly.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"> 

</head>
<body>

    <table id="myTable" align="center" style="width:600px;table-layout:fixed;" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>Fruit ID</th>  
            <th>Fruit Name</th>  
          </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>apple</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>orange</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>lemon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>banana</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>grapes</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>  
    </table>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>  

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').dataTable();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent them from "stretching out", put everything into a div with the class `.container` like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

That will keep everything neat and tidy.

Another option would be to put everything into a column with the classes `col-auto mx-auto` like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto mx-auto">
        content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`col-auto` will shrink the column to the size of the content and `mx-auto` will horizontally center that column.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers